# Blochs Theorem realtion to free mean path?

Tags: condensed-matter

In 'The Oxford Solid State Basics' by S.H.Simon when referring to a shortcoming of the free electron model the following question is posed:

> .. charged atomic nuclei, every few $\overset{\circ}{A}$ngstroms in a metal, why do the electrons not scatter from these atoms? (We will discuss this in Chapter 15 - the resolution is a result of Bloch's theorem).

In chapter 15 Bloch's theorem is given by:

> **Bloch's Theorem:** An electron in a periodic potential has eigenstates of the form $$\newcommand{\vecb}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} $$ $$ \Psi_{\vecb{k}}^\alpha(\vecb{r})=e^{i\vecb{k}\cdot \vecb{r}}u_{\vecb{k}}^\alpha(\vecb{r})$$
>   where $u_{\vecb{k}}^\alpha$ is periodic in the unit cell and $\vecb{k}$ (the crystal momentum) can be chosen within the first Brillouin zone.

But I cannot find an answer to the question posed above. Thus my question here is: Why does Bloch's theorem resolve the issue of a large free mean path of electrons in atoms?

Comment: It is explained on page 170.